# Multi-table uniqueness constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following setup. A SalesPrice can have many customers and many products. A product can have many sales prices and so can a customer. I want to enforce a constraint on the SalesPrice, so that each customer can only be assigned to another product once, even across SalesPrices.

```
SalesPrice1 = C1, C2, P1
SalesPrice2 = C1, C3, P1, P3
```

Above, in both SalesPrices, customer 1 (C1) is linked with the same Product (P1) twice, which should not be possible. I get kind of confused because I use a lot of join tables, so how would i accomplish this?

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customer_price_relations
  has_many :sales_prices, through: :customer_price_relations (join table)

class SalesPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_sales_prices, dependent: :destroy (join table)
  has_many :products, through: :product_sales_prices
  has_many :customer_price_relations, dependent: :destroy (join table)
  has_many :customers, through: :customer_price_relations  

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :product_sales_prices
  has_many   :sales_prices, through: :product_sales_prices (join table)
```

Assignment method:

```
def create_sales_price(company_id: nil, product_ids: nil, customer_ids: nil,
                       name: nil, margin_percentage: nil)
  sales_price = nil

  transaction do 
    sales_price = self.new({
      company_id:        company_id,
      name:              name,
      margin_percentage: margin_percentage
    })
    sales_price.save!

    customer_ids.each do |customer_id|
      customer_price_relation = CustomerPriceRelation.new({
        customer_id: customer_id,
        sales_price_id: sales_price.id
      })
      customer_price_relation.save!
    end

    product_ids.each do |product_id|
      price_document_relation = ProductSalesPrice.new({
        sales_price_id: sales_price.id,
        product_id: product_id
      })
      price_document_relation.save!
    end
  end

  return sales_price
end
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I don't see how customers are even related to products in this setup...

Comment: through the SalesPrice model

Comment: that's not an actual relation, just because you can do `customer.sales_prices.first.products` doesn't mean they're related, you're actually just jumping a relation there

Comment: Im confused, there must be a way to enforce the described constraint, that is exemplified

Comment: sure but since there's no actual relation between customer and product then active record can't help you here. You'd have to implement the constraint yourself and place it in a before_create or update. 1 question: if the customer can have many sales_prices and sales_prices can have many products but a customer can only have 1 product through the many sales prices it has, how are you going to take care of that? constrain the customer to only have 1 sales prices as well?

Comment: Well a customer can have many products, but can only be assigned the SAME product once. So there cant be two different sales prices that where there is overlap between a customer and product

Comment: Can you post code on how you assign products to customer?

Comment: As an aside, there's no need to do `model = MyModel.new(...); model.save!` when you can do `MyModel.create!(...)` instead.